# Como pasar una variable desde ajax a una web abierta mediante location.href

Tags: javascript, ajax

Muy buenas, tengo una funcion ajax  que llama a un archivo y me devuelve una variable, una vez tengo esa variable que es  "objJson", me gustaría abrir una pagina  y pasarle esa variable objJson.
Espero que se entienda.

```
function login(){
usuario=$('#idUsuario').val(); 
clave=$('#idClave').val(); 

var parametros = {
        "ap":"4c",
        "usuario":usuario,
        "clave":clave,
    }

    $.ajax ({
        data: parametros,
        url: "/l/php/login.php",
        type: "POST",

    success: function(data){
        var objJson=JSON.parse(data);
        location.href ='principal.html';
    });
}
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes al menos dos opciones:

Podrías pasarlo en la URL y luego obtenerla en la nueva página:

```
location.href='principal.html?objJson=' + data;
```

Asumiendo que ambas páginas están en el mismo dominio, podrías pasarlo por el localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('objJson',data);
location.href='principal.html;
```

Y en la página destino hacer un simple

```
let objJson=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('objJson'));
```

Ejemplo del primer caso:

```js
let direccion = 'http://www.example.com/principal.html';

let objJson={hola:"texto"};

direccion+= '?objJson=' + JSON.stringify(objJson);

// En la página destino:
let url = new URL(direccion); // En la página destino sería location.href
let param = JSON.parse(url.searchParams.get('objJson'));
console.log(param.hola);
```

Comment: El problema es que según tengo entendido, Java Script no puede recibir variables por url, ya antes lo intente y al final tuve que convertir la pagina en php para poder recibir las variables por url. Hay alguna forma de recibir la variable que le paso por url desde Java Script?

Comment: Te he puesto algo de código extra para explicarlo

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, era un problema el de el paso de variables que arrastraba durante mucho tiempo, ya lo tengo solucionado con este código. Solo tengo una duda, ¿Habria alguna forma de que la información no se viera en la barra de direcciones? Muchas gracias otra vez.

Comment: Yo usaría realmente localStorage para no necesitar eso. Si realmente no puedes usarlo, entonces puedes "ofuscar" el valor del parámetro para que no sea legible, pero no hay manera de que no salga en la barra de direcciones

Comment: El problema de localStorage es que segun tengo entendido, se guarda en el pc cliente, y es información que no me interesa que puedan modificar de algúna forma.

Comment: Puedes borrarla en cuanto lo leas

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo, pensaré en las opciones que me has dado y decidire cual me conviene. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

deberías enviarle la variable desde la misma URL. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
function login(){
 usuario=$('#idUsuario').val(); 
 clave=$('#idClave').val(); 

 var parametros = {
    "ap":"4c",
    "usuario":usuario,
    "clave":clave,
 }

 $.ajax ({
    data: parametros,
    url: "/l/php/login.php",
    type: "POST",

 success: function(data){
    var objJson=JSON.parse(data);
    location.href ='principal.html?variable=' + objJson;
 });
}
```

Comment: En caso de que el la reciba entre las variables pasadas por GET

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta, las dos me han sido validas. Un saludo.